# iOS scroll view making content disabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I've registration form and when keyboard is hiding I'm changing content inset and offset and after that I can't catch any touch event in my view.

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

    CGRect keyboardRect = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    //calculating values

    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint];
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 200);
    self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = self.scrollView.contentInset;
}
```

If I'll remove changing of offset or inset al works great. But I need to set offset and inset.

Comment: Is your `self.scrollView.contentSize` appropriate?

Comment: @IanMacDonald Yes it is equal to (320, 480) always and I'm not changing it anywhere else.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm running into the exact same thing. Once my scrollview moves into where the insets would be, the content is basically dead at that point, no touch events get through.

Comment: @AdamVenturella No I don't.